# Uploading external file in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to upload a remote file through window popup using protractor but none of the solutions work.

Request someone to please help

My code is something like:-

var remote = require('F:/untitled/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');
                    browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());

```
                var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
                //files
                //var fileElem = element(by.css('div.file-uploader'));

                var absolutePath = 'F:/1778.docx';
                browser.switchTo().activeElement();
                browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px';arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileElem.getWebElement());
                fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
                browser.driver.sleep(100);*/
```

source code is something like

File Drop not
            available

```
    <div ng-show="dropAvailable" ng-switch="buttonType" layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: fab -->
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: icon -->
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: text-icon --><div class="file-upload-button ng-scope" ng-switch-when="text-icon">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ng-binding" aria-label="Add Attachment">Add Attachment <span ng-class="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span></button>
        </div>
        <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  -->
    </div>
</div><!-- end ngIf: canUploadFn() -->
<!-- Display the existing files -->
<!-- ngIf: showAttachments -->
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you should post what you have tried already with some specific examples together with any errors that you are seeing.

Comment: Please post the code, html and error if there is any when you run the test

Comment: I see no error but nothing eneters in the window that opens after clicking thebutton

Comment: can someone please help, I am still stuck there